# SWT: Differentiating between selection and typing in a combo

Tags: java, swt, jface

Consider the following Java (SWT) code:

```
private static ComboViewer createViewer(final Shell shell) {
  final ComboViewer v = new ComboViewer(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
  v.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
  v.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
  v.setInput(new String[]{"value 1", "value 2"});
  return v;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
  Display display = new Display();
  Shell shell = new Shell(display);
  shell.setSize(200, 60); 
  shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  final ComboViewer v = createViewer(shell);

  // This wires up the userSelectedSomething method correctly
  v.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent event) {
      userSelectedSomething();
    }
  });

  shell.open();
  while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
      display.sleep();
    }
  }
  display.dispose();
}

public static void userSelectedSomething() {
  // This should be called *only if* the user selected from the drop-down
}

public static void userTypedSomething() {
  // This should be called *only if* the user typed in the combo
}
```

I want to call the `userTypedSomething` method only if the user typed into the combo (and not when they selected from the drop-down). What listener should I add to achieve this? Adding a modify listener to the combo viewer with `v.getCombo().addModifyListener(...)` is no good as this is triggered for both typing and selection from the combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to listen to keyboard input, I would suggest listening to `SWT.KeyUp`.

This should be a good starting point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Combo combo = new Combo(shell, SWT.NONE);

    combo.add("First");
    combo.add("Second");

    combo.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            System.out.println("Selected: " + combo.getItem(combo.getSelectionIndex()));
        }
    });

    combo.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            System.out.println("Typed");
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Sadly not. Adding a verify listener with v.getCombo().addVerifyListener results in the listener being triggered (twice!) for selections from the drop-down as well as once for typing. Arguably this is a bug for JFace to fix...

Comment: @DavidNorth Check my answer again. I added a code snippet. You will have to check the length of the `text` of the event. User typing should equal a length of 1. As I said, it's not optimal, but a starting point.

Comment: @DavidNorth Edited answer again. You can use the `SWT.KeyUp` event to watch keyboard input.

Comment: That's very close, but doesn't detect the user using cut/paste/delete on the right-click menu to edit the text. However, it is as close as it's possible to get without fixing SWT, so I'm marking your answer as correct and have raised https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389587 for a proper fix in SWT.

Answer (score 5):

```
private static ComboViewer createViewer(final Shell shell) {
    final ComboViewer v = new ComboViewer(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
    v.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
    v.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    v.setInput(new String[]{"value 1", "value 2"});
    return v;
  }

  private static boolean userTyped;
  private static int index = -1;

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(200, 60); 
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final ComboViewer v = createViewer(shell);
    /*
     * invoked multiple times when combo selection happens
     * invoked once when user types
     */
    v.getCombo().addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {



      @Override
      public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
         userTyped = (e.keyCode != 0);
      }
    });



 v.getCombo().addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

  @Override
  public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {

    Combo c = (Combo)e.widget;

    if(userTyped || index == c.getSelectionIndex() || c.getSelectionIndex() == -1)
    {
      userTypedOrEditedSomething();
    }
    index = c.getSelectionIndex();
  }
});

    // This wires up the userSelectedSomething method correctly
    v.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
      @Override
      public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        userSelectedSomething();
      }
    });

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }

  public static void userSelectedSomething() {
    // This should be called *only if* the user selected from the drop-down
    System.out.println("User selected");
  }

  public static void userTypedOrEditedSomething() {
    // This should be called *only if* the user typed in the combo
    System.out.println("User typed or edited");
  }
```

I would suggest you to use Verify event instead Key UP as you might endup handling lot of things (arrow keys, magic keys...etc). Verify is also Key Event but it filter out **ALT,CNTRL,SHIFT** combination. When user types just check for keycode!=0.

As you pointed out, when you use CNTRL+V ,Right click Menu paste....combo doesn't consider it as key event but it fires verify event to make sure the clipboard text is valid for combo or not. I think this is how it should work as Menu item selection and Key event on combo are different things.
you can always monitor all key events for special actions like copy/paste/delete.

the above sample code should be able to perform what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that looks potentially workable. If Eclipse don't respond to my bug I'll try your approach.

Comment: When I press the up/down arrow keys when the focus is in the text field, a verify event is recieved with a keyCode of 0

Answer (score 0):

A small impovement to @sambi.reddy answer, taking into account not to consider user has typed something when the arrow keys, pg down or pg up are used to select next/previous item:

```
private static ComboViewer createViewer(final Shell shell) {
    final ComboViewer v = new ComboViewer(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
    v.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
    v.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    v.setInput(new String[]{"value 1", "value 2"});
    return v;
  }

  private static boolean userTyped;
  private static int index = -1;

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(200, 60); 
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final ComboViewer v = createViewer(shell);
    /*
     * invoked multiple times when combo selection happens
     * invoked once when user types
     */
    v.getCombo().addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {
      @Override
      public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
         userTyped = if (ev.keyCode != 0 && !List.of(SWT.ARROW_UP, SWT.ARROW_DOWN, SWT.PAGE_DOWN, SWT.PAGE_UP).contains(ev.keyCode));
      }
    });
}
```

v.getCombo().addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

@Override
public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {

```
Combo c = (Combo)e.widget;

if(userTyped || index == c.getSelectionIndex() || c.getSelectionIndex() == -1)
{
  userTypedOrEditedSomething();
}
index = c.getSelectionIndex();
```

}
});

```
// This wires up the userSelectedSomething method correctly
v.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
  @Override
  public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent event) {
    userSelectedSomething();
  }
});

shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
    display.sleep();
  }
}
display.dispose();
```

}

public static void userSelectedSomething() {
// This should be called *only if* the user selected from the drop-down
System.out.println("User selected");
}

public static void userTypedOrEditedSomething() {
// This should be called *only if* the user typed in the combo
System.out.println("User typed or edited");
}